# SD Card Mount Failed with Waveshare ESP32 using Arduino IDE

Tags: esp32, spi, sd-card

I'm currently working on a project using an ESP32 (the [Waveshare ESP32 Driver Board](https://www.waveshare.com/e-paper-esp32-driver-board.htm)), and I am trying to read data from an SD card, but consistently getting a "SD Card Mount Failed" error. I am using the [Adafruit SD card reader breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/254) and the Arduino IDE.

Here's how I've wired the SD card reader to the ESP32

```
SD card     ESP32
-------     -----
3.3V        3.3V
GND         GND
CLK         pin 18 (SCK)
DO          pin 19 (MISO)
DI          pin 23 (MOSI)
CS          pin 5 (SS)
```

And here's the relevant code I'm using to setup and test the SD card:

```
#define SCK  18
#define MISO  19
#define MOSI  23
#define CS  5

int setup_sd_card() {
  
  SPIClass spi = SPIClass(VSPI);
  spi.begin(SCK, MISO, MOSI, CS);

  if (!SD.begin(CS,spi,80000000)) {
    Serial.println("ERROR: SD Card Mount Failed");
    return -1;
  }
  uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();
  
  if(cardType == CARD_NONE){
    Serial.println("ERROR: No SD card attached");
    return -1;
  }

  // Code to print out SD card details...

  return 1;
}
```

I've triple-checked my wiring but the code always fails at `if (!SD.begin(CS,spi,80000000))`. I've tried 3 different SD cards of different sizes, all formatted to FAT32 (64GB, 256GB, 1024GB)

Could the issue be related to the ESP32 not being a stock one because it has some hardware for driving an e-paper screen? Here is the schematic: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/8/80/E-Paper_ESP32_Driver_Board_Schematic.pdf

[image: Waveshare ESP32 Schematic]

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue or what else I could try to debug this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Waveshare esp32 appears to use the following SPI pins for the screen. P13:  spi clk; P14:  spi mosi; P15:  cs (not  shared). For clk, miso and mosi you should use the same pins. Try printing out the existing values of clk, miso and mosi without (re-) defining them. Only the cs pin is unique to the peripheral. The remaining SPI pins are a shared bus.

Comment: I moved the SPIClass declaration to a global variable and changed the frequency down to 4 from 80 but I'm getting the same result. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I also printed out the existing values of MOSI/MISO/SCK/SS after deleting my redefinition of them and they are:

MOSI: 23
MISO: 19
SCK: 18
SS: 5

; I can try using the same SPI pins the screen uses and see if that works. I'll update this when I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your code.

First I think you have a typo in the frequency. Default frequency is 4 MHz, but your parameter in `begin` is 80 MHz, which I doubt will work.

You initialize the `spi` object on the stack in the function and then supply it to the SD instance. The `spi` object on stack will be removed when the function ends and the SD object will crash. It has to be an allocation on heap as `SPIClass* spi = new SPIClass(VSPI);` or a global variable `SPIClass spi(VSPI);`.

And since you use the default pins of VSPI you can use just `spi.begin()` without the pin numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a faulty SD card.

I had tried other SD cards but must have used incorrect wiring for them.

EDIT: Here is the updated code:

```
#define CS        5
#define SCK       18
#define MOSI      23
#define MISO      19

SPIClass spi(VSPI);

int setup_sd_card() {
  spi.begin(SCK, MISO, MOSI, CS);

  if (!SD.begin(CS,spi,4000000)) {
    Serial.println("ERROR: SD Card Mount Failed");
    delay(1000);
    return -1;
  }
  Serial.println("Finished initializing SD card. Getting card type...");

  uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();
  
  if(cardType == CARD_NONE){
    Serial.println("ERROR: No SD card attached");
    delay(1000);
    return -1;
  }

  Serial.print("SD Card Type: ");
  if (cardType == CARD_MMC){
    Serial.println("MMC");
  } else if(cardType == CARD_SD){
    Serial.println("SDSC");
  } else if(cardType == CARD_SDHC){
    Serial.println("SDHC");
  } else {
    Serial.println("UNKNOWN");
  }
  Serial.printf("Total space: %lluMB\n", SD.totalBytes() / (1024 * 1024));
  Serial.printf("Used space: %lluMB\n", SD.usedBytes() / (1024 * 1024));

  Serial.println("SUCCESS! (SD CARD)");
  
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: does it work with the code as it is in the Question?

Comment: I just edited my answer to add the code that works. It's the same as above with the two suggestions given in the comments.

Comment: so it doesn't `begin` at 80 mega? what about 8 mega?